# Getting 104 Connection reset error after 5 minutes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking

I have a cluster on GKE and one of my deployments run tornado web app to receive http requests.
This deployment is exposed by a LoadBalancer.
I send a simple http request to the LoadBalancer ip, which must run on server side for ~10 minutes.
After exactly 5 minutes, I get:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I tried:

- Using the communication locally on my computer (both client and server) and haven't got the reset.
- I made kubectl port-forward directly to the deployment (local client -> kubectl port-forward -> deployment -> server) and haven't got the connection reset.
  So basically I'm pretty sure it's on the loadbalnacer side.
- I made a backend config with this configuration:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-bsc-backendconfig
spec:
  timeoutSec: 3600
```

and my loadbalancer is configured like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"5000":"my-bsc-backendconfig"}'
  creationTimestamp: "2020-12-24T10:08:54Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    name: wesnapp-flask
  name: wesnapp-flask-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "14652233"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/wesnapp-flask-service
  uid: a922e9cb-4702-481f-b1a9-e09df1653ff7
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.64.9.113
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31429
    port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    name: wesnapp-flask
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: x.x.x.x
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Hello, have you tried to reproduce the same behavior in different environment (for example `minikube`)? The timeout could be specific to your client <-> server configuration (server setting for timeouts for example).

Comment: @DawidKruk Yes I have tried, this situation has nothing to do with my server-client sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is right. GCE LoadBalancer kills the connection.
As mentioned in [this Google document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal), there is a `Stream idle timeout` configured to 300 seconds (5 minutes) and can't be changed. HTTP streams become idle after 5 minutes without activity.

Comment: Going forward, I'd suggest that you take a look at [`Celery`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) project, in case you're not familiar with it already. It might fit your project architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm already using dask as my task manager.